# Download file from database with jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to download a file from database. In download.php page I have done everything required and if I write `header("Location: ../php/download.php?mid=3")` in any pages it will download file number 3 properly! but when I call function below at the same page it does not work!! I don't know why!!
Thank you in advance!

```
   function download(mid) {
     window.alert("hi"); // this works
     $.get("../php/download.php?mid=3");
     return false;
   }
```

Comment: Is the path to the download file correct? Or does the function not fire? What do you mean by "it does not work!"?

Comment: ajax isn't for file downloads. use a redirect instead, e.g. `window.location = ...`.

Comment: you need to be more specific, the function wont work because it's not being called.

Answer (score 4):

That ajax call is ignoring the response from the server, effectively "doing nothing".

You need to write something like

```
$.get("../php/download.php?mid=3", function(response){
    // do something with the response
});
```

If what you actually want is for the **user** to download the file, I don't see why you would need ajax for that, a regular link would do as long as the headers are set properly in download.php ("content-disposition:attachment")